# Select case when (select * from

Tags: sql, sql-server, if, case

Задача ставить пометку **(Д)** перед именем заказчика, если заключен договор и не истекла дата окончания договора, логика подсказывает такую структуру:

```sql
case when 
    (isnull(SELECT OrgName FROM Dogs
    WHERE Dogs.OrgName = Orders.Cust_Name
    AND Dogs.NDog <> '0'
    AND Dogs.Duration > convert(date, GetDate()))
then '(Д)' else '') + " " + Orders.Cust_Name as StatusDogs,
```

Но она к сожалению не работает, сам по себе **Select** в отдельном запросе нормально возвращает результат

Вопрос решен с помощью пользователя **Teran**, вот правильный код:

```sql
case when exists (SELECT OrgName FROM Dogs
        WHERE Dogs.OrgName = Orders.Cust_Name
        AND Dogs.NDog <> '0'
        AND Dogs.Duration > convert(date, GetDate()))
    then '(Д)' else '' end + ' ' + Orders.Cust_Name as StatusDogs,
```

Comment: как то интересно вы результат запроса хотите проверить в `isnull`. вы либо джойн сделайте к основному запросу, либо какой нить exists используйте, а не isnull, он поле на null проверяет, а не результат запроса на пустоту

Comment: [UPDATE (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms177523(v%3dsql.105)).

Comment: `end` у вас еще отсутствует, кстати

Comment: Спасибо @teran, заменил isnull на exists и все пошло, а END потерял при переписывании кода)